# How to add Angular attributes to dynamically generated element with a function as the parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to JavaScript and AngularJS.

I have been attempting to add an 'ng-click' attribute to a link element with a function as the parameter using the code below:

```
var aTag1 = document.createElement('a');               
aTag1.setAttribute('ng-click', "setID(" + response.data[i].resultID + ")");
```

JavaScript seems to acknowledge that the attribute has been added to the element but the function isn't run when the link is clicked. I'm sure there is a simple answer but I haven't been able to find one for some reason.

Comment: The issue you linked to is a TypeScript issue, not a JavaScript one, but thank you for linking it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the element and set the attributes using your method, please compile the new content using `$compile` and then append.

```
var aTag1 = document.createElement('a');
aTag1.innerHTML = 'testing'
aTag1.setAttribute('ng-click', "setID(" + "'test'" + ")");
var test = $compile(aTag1)(scope);
element.append(test);
```

Please check the below working example, also this logic should be done inside an angular directive, since we are modifying the element.

```js
angular.module('components', []).directive('helloWorld', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '='
    },
    template: '<span>Hello {{name}}</span>',
    link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
      var aTag1 = document.createElement('a');
      aTag1.innerHTML = 'testing'
      aTag1.setAttribute('ng-click', "setID(" + "'test'" + ")");
      var test = $compile(aTag1)(scope);
      element.append(test);
      scope.setID = function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      }
    }
  }
})

angular.module('myApp', ['components']).controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'test';
}]);
```

```css
.ng-scope {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='myctrl'>
  <hello-world name="name"></hello-world>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*FYI Example of set attribute, remove attribute*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<body>
<button ng-click="getAttr()">
  Get Attribute value
</button>
<br/>
<button ng-click="setAttr()">
  Set Attribute value
</button>
<br/>
<button ng-click="removeAttr()">
  Remove Attribute value
</button>
<br/>
<div myattr="val" id="divID">
  Attribute DIV
</div>
<script>
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getAttr = function() {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     alert(myEl.attr('myattr'));
    }
    $scope.setAttr = function() {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     myEl.attr('myattr',"attr val");
     alert("attribute set");
    }
    $scope.removeAttr = function() {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     myEl.removeAttr('myattr');
     alert("attribute removed");
    }
}
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```