# I want to set Angular directives in Html tag as attributes at run time using JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and currently I am creating an application.

My question is simple, we can

```
      <select [(ngModel)]="departments" >

      </select>
```

but I want to do this thing at runtime created select tag using JavaScript like this

```
        let etdsss1 = document.createElement("td");

        let select  = document.createElement("select");

        select.setAttribute("[(ngModel)]","selected");
```

In other words, I want to bind angular directives at runtime is it possible.

but it is generating error.

```
      ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[(ngModel)]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

I know it is not right way to do this; I want to ask, can we do this runtime?

Comment: i think this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796404/document-setattribute-ngmodel-angular

Comment: You should try to avoid heading down this path if at all possible. Can you give us some more information on why you would need to do this, rather than just using an angular template?

For more context -- angular templates are compiled into javascript before they reach the DOM. Those attributes don't have the same power once they reach the DOM -- they are instructions for the angular template compiler only.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782906